# Standalone object browser for C#

Tags: c#, .net

In Visual Studio, I can press F12 on a standard class to view its declaration, for example the Stream class, and Visual Studio will show it in a tab titled "Stream [from metadata]":

[image]

Is there a standalone object browser that offers the equivalent functionality?

If possible, it should be free, and lightweight (1-2mb installation). I won't to be able to use it when coding in the Snippy tool from Jon Skeet, without firing VS just to look up a declaration.

Comment: Perhaps [ilspy](http://ilspy.net/)?

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AlexK. Looks like you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex K mentioned in the comments above.
[ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) is a good choice in this case.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Jetbrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It's free and meanwhile has more features than ILSpy, it can e.g. make use of PDB files and Microsoft source servers and is extensible via plugins.

[image: dotPeek showing FileSystemWatcher]

Comment: Thanks. I'll just add that the installer was extremely heavy - first it downloaded another bigger installer and took its time for it, and then it offered me many products I wasn't interested in. Then it started "pulling packages" and again took a lot of time. I felt like I was installing Eclipse, instead of a lightweight standalone tool. Compared to that ILSpy was just a 2 mb zip file containing everything you need.

Comment: @sashoalm: you're right. I still had version 1.5. It seems the new version is part of a larger installer :-(